# xml error - Attribute name "mod_expires.c" associated with an element type "IfModule" must be followed by the ' = ' character

Tags: xml, .htaccess

I tried to use `.htaccess` in `xml` template to leverage Browser Caching. This is the code-

```
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
  ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
  </IfModule>
```

xml is giving error - **Attribute name "mod_expires.c" associated with an element type "IfModule" must be followed by the ' = ' character.** How can i correct it ?

Answer (score 2):

You missunderstood something that is no xml tag even it it looks like that is a so called directive. You cannot parse this as xml.

See also the documentation about the if directive: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#ifmodule

Comment: then where should i put .htaccess file

Comment: Just put that file in the directory where it should been read by the server. Please make sure that your server configuration that there is a line "AllowOverride All"